# Why does Control.Monad.Morph.hoist have a Monad constraint?

Tags: haskell, monads, typeclass, functor

`Control.Monad.Morph` includes

```
class MFunctor t where
  hoist :: Monad m => (forall a. m a -> n a) -> t m b -> t n b
```

As far as I can tell, none of the included instances use the `Monad m` constraint. How might one do so? Are there valid instances that use the constraint (it's a bit hard for me to imagine how, given that `hoist id = id`)? What's the significance of the constraint being on `m` and not `n`?

Comment: I was expecting something to break in [`Control.Monad.Trans.Compose`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmorph-1.0.6/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Compose.html), but everything compiles fine without `Monad m` on `hoist`...

Comment: Maybe because it only makes sense for monads? It's a functor over a monad transformer (stack), as far as I can see.

Comment: @Alec `Control.Monad.Trans.Compose` doesn't have an `MFunctor` instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Control.Monad.Morph` is a spinoff from [pipes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes), so I'd guess it's there because the `MFunctor` instance for `Proxy` needs it... And sure enough it's [used there](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.2.0/docs/src/Pipes-Internal.html#unsafeHoist).

> ```
> instance MFunctor (Proxy a' a b' b) where
>     hoist nat p0 = go (observe p0)
>       where
>         go p = case p of
>             Request a' fa  -> Request a' (\a  -> go (fa  a ))
>             Respond b  fb' -> Respond b  (\b' -> go (fb' b'))
>             M          m   -> M (nat (m >>= \p' -> return (go p')))
>             Pure    r      -> Pure r
> ```

I don't think it's needed though. `m >>= return . f` is `fmap f m`. It probably should be a `Functor` constraint and that code predates the implementation of the monad-applicative proposal.

Comment: Do you know what that's doing? Is the `Monad` (or `Functor`) constraint required for the semantics, or only efficiency?

Comment: It's mapping `hoist nat` recursively inside `m`. A `Functor` constraint shouldn't be a surprising requirement for any transformer `t m a` of a form like `m (t m a)`.